# Properties of localization of fractional ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I am reading the following proof of properties of localization of fractional ideals. I think I have missed something fundamental here---Why do we need M and N to be fractional ideals here at all? Why doesn't this hold for general submodules of some R-module?
[image]

Comment: The submodules of R are are ideals. I can't see where is the generality here.

Comment: @user26857 Sorry I mean submodules of some R-module in general. I have edited the question.

Comment: If they are submodules then what $MN$ means? (The second part works well for submodules.)

Comment: @user26857 oh I see… thank you so much!